# Can I retire without Trauma?

Tags: blades-in-the-dark

One of my players in my Blades in the Dark game was asking me some detailed questions about exactly how retirement works. According to the Stash & Retirement section on page 43,

> When you mark your character’s final trauma and they retire, the amount of
>   coin they’ve managed to stash away determines their fate. Your stash tracker
>   is on your character sheet.

This implies to me that the only way a scoundrel can retire is through accumulating enough trauma to need to leave the crew. Can a scoundrel retire before that point? If a scoundrel accumulates 40 Stash, and decides to leave the crimesman life before filling their Trauma, can they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yeah, sure.

> Maybe someone wants to retire their character and play someone new.
>
> -- Blades in the Dark p.207, "The Dark Future"

No reason you can't drop out of the game whenever. Your stash is also your lifestyle, after all, so you might as well keep on living it.

It is suggested, in that same section, that you don't just bail on the crew when you feel like it, but that your crew ties a bow around some season of their lives, the clock jumps ahead, and you have a sit-down and discuss what's happening. Maybe some people shift playbooks, maybe your crew shifts focus, maybe somebody retires, maybe everybody retires and the old squad heads take up the reins.

Heck, maybe the bow you tie is the crew getting together for the big score that is getting your file away from the Bluecoats and settling up all your old debts so you can almost kind of live a mostly honest life.